# Reference on Malcev completion

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, algebraic-geometry, reference-request

I need a reference for learning Malcev completion, its associated group scheme, and Lie algebra.

Thanks!

Comment: I am not familiar with this construction. However, some references are mentioned in ncatlab article: http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Mal%27cev+completion

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the following online documents:

- "The Malcev Completion for Groups"
  http://math.univ-lille1.fr/~fresse/OperadHomotopyBook/MalcevCompletion.pdf
- "Relative Malcev Completion" by P. Dalakov
  http://math.mit.edu/conferences/talbot/2011/notes/talbot_2011_16_peter_notes.pdf
- "Fillings in Nilpotent Groups" by A. Lukyanenko
  http://lukyanenko.net/papers/FillingsInNilpotentGroups.pdf
- "On $l-$Adic Pro-Algebraic and Relative Pro$-l$ Fundamental Groups" by J. Pridham
  http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~jpridham/heid.pdf
- "Malcev's Completion of a Group and Differential Forms" by B. Cenkl and R. Porter
  http://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.jdg/1214435841

Comment: Thank you very much for this very complete answer.

Comment: You're welcome :)